# MongoDB C# 2.0 Driver: How many MongoClients respectively Sockets per Web Application?

Tags: c#, mongodb, sockets, asp.net-web-api, mongodb-.net-driver

> Typically you only create one MongoClient instance for a given cluster
>   and use it across your application. Creating multiple MongoClients
>   will, however, still share the same pool of connections if and only if
>   the connection strings are identical.

Source: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/getting_started/quick_tour/

Our situation is that we have two different "clusters".

We do not work with replication or sharding, but we have two different databases.

It means that some of our API functions will fetch data from one database, whereas other API functions get the data from the second database.
This is hard coded.

We created a SelectDatabase method in each class, which then creates a MongoClient with the given settings.

The same class will always access the same database.

I expected that the driver would handle then the number of seconds in an "optimum way".

But it turned out, that each time I refresh the browser, a new Web API Controller call is done and therefore also a new SelectDatabase call.
And that resulted in a new socket every time (checked with TCPView).

So of course each API Controller call should cause SelectDatabase, but I think it is an overkill to create a socket each time.

We are creating new MongoClients like this:

```
//Creating multiple MongoClients will, however, still share the same pool of connections 
//if and only if the connection strings are identical.          
MongoClientSettings clientSettings1 = new MongoClientSettings()
{
    Server = new MongoServerAddress(host, port),
    ClusterConfigurator = builder =>
    {
        builder.ConfigureCluster(settings => settings.With(serverSelectionTimeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(serverSelectionTimeoutInSeconds)));
    }
};
```

What is the optimum number of simultaneously opened Sockets (between Web Application and Database), respectively MongoClient instances, in our Project situation?

1. Web Browser "Socket" Life cycle should only cause the Web application to create 1 socket to the database
2. The Web Application should use just one socket, each per database, completely independent of how many Web Browser or Sockets are open to the web application.
3. You should open a new connection each time you have a Web API call

I run some Postman test where I created a few hundred API calls and I saw that it was running out of resources respectively into timeouts. I saw that it run better, when I was choosing approach number 2 instead of 3.
But I am concerned that the different tasks created when the Web API gets called so often could interfere somehow then on a Socket level to make errors occur.

**Update**
I made two tests: 
The first was based on the principle that on each request a new MongoClient is generated. TCPView showed me that a new socket is opened on each request.
The second test was with a singleton pattern which allows me to access every time the same two MongoClients. The second test only used two sockets.
I also need to say that I changed the asynchronous call so that the methods is blocked until it returns (for simplicity I did not want these Task return types in every method).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made some trials and it turns out that creating multiple MongoClients will NOT share the same pool of connections if you used a MongoClientSettings object, even if the connection string parameters (host, port) are the same.

MongoDB documentation probably meant "connection strings" literally, that is, only strings.

In short, the following works as intended:

```
_client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
```

But not the following:

```
MongoClientSettings clientSettings = new MongoClientSettings()
{
    Server = new MongoServerAddress(host, port),
    ClusterConfigurator = builder =>
    {
        builder.ConfigureCluster(settings => settings.With(serverSelectionTimeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(serverSelectionTimeoutInSeconds)));
    }
};


_client = new MongoClient(clientSettings);
```

Even if you used the very same MongoClientSettings object from a singleton, you still get different connection pools. I also verified that.

Comment: This make sense, since I saw that a new socket has been opened for each request.

Comment: @Matthias Though you say that you checked with the same MongoClientSettings instance, I see that ClusterKey takes into account all of the settings to find the same cluster instance. https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/8e117995372ebc2147619a495287d8dbf4babf4e/src/MongoDB.Driver/ClusterKey.cs#L231
So my assumption that the problem is in having an anonymous method that refers a local variable. Every time it is assigned to ClusterConfigurator it is a different delegate. Thus the references do not equal and a ClusterKey doesn't match an existing key.

Answer (score 2):

One MongoClient instance doesn't mean one socket, inside it has a pool of connections and you can control the minimum and maximum of the pool size. The default value of the maximum pool size is 100, which means it can grow up to 100 open connections/sockets. 
Based on the documentation it doesn't matter how you create your MongoClient, because you should end up with 2 connection pools anyway, because you have 2 different connection strings. But I would go with number 2, one MongoClient instance per database because that is the recommended way to go for [all mongo clients](http://blog.mongolab.com/2013/11/deep-dive-into-connection-pooling/) no matter the technology. 
In your case when you ran the tests with Postman it is possible that the timeouts came from the web server? What is good about the mongodb .NET client is that it is exposing async methods so you can async all the way to the web api controller. This should make your web application scale because all the asp.net threads will be reused and not blocked on the IO.
And you should not worry about mixing sockets/connections because one MongoClient doesn't mean one socket. Underneath there are many connections being used and they are only reused when they finished their previous work. If you take a look at the code of the [csharp-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver) you can see it looks pretty professional :)

Comment: That is exactly what I believe is not true "Based on the documentation it doesn't matter how you create your MongoClient, because you should end up with 2 connection pools anyway, because you have 2 different connection strings." I think more relevant is probably how you deal with tasks asynchronous/synchronous MongoDB driver calls.

Comment: The timeouts where from the MongoDB server not web server. I thought that it just opened too many sockets in too short time period while not closing the unused sockets.

Comment: To be honest I looked at the code for about 1h and I couldn't see where the connection pool is reused for instances with the same connection strings. So it is better to use just one instance of MongoClient per cluster and this is the general recommendation, no matter the tech. But it says pretty clear in the csharp driver docs that having the same connection string leads to the same pool. Indeed it is very important to go async all the way for a scalable application.

Comment: I would really interesting to understand all the "mechanics" down to the socket and task level. I am wondering how to get more knowledge here. What happens for example in the singleton pattern when two calls (two threads, access the same socket resource the same time, which will obviously happen, when I use two MongoClients.)

Comment: See the CluserRegistry https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver/ClusterRegistry.cs - there is your singleton. It means that if you create a new MongoClient with the same settings then underneath it uses the same instance of ICluster. MultiServerCluser and SIngleServerCluster implement Cluster which implements ICluster. In your case it will be a SingleServerCluster which has an instance of IClusterableServer, implemented by ClusterableServer which has a connection pool. So yes the docs are right, it is the same connection pool for the same connection string

Comment: OK. Same pool, but how does it decide whether to open a new socket or not.

Comment: Look at the file https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver.Core/Core/ConnectionPools/ExclusiveConnectionPool.cs Here you have a class ListConnectionHolder which holds a list of PooledConnection. You can see the 2 methods Acquire and Return. Then you can see how this class is used in ExclusiveConnectionPool (which instance can be found in IClusterableServer) with functions like AcquireConnection, EnsureMinSizeAsync, ReleaseConnection